# Compare two datatables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

DataTable One contains only one column (Code)

```
Code
3
7
```

And Second Datatable also contains only one column (ProductCode)

```
ProductCode
2
3
6
7
```

I want to compare if all values of first datatable exist in second datatable using the best technique. currently i am using for each but one time it is FALSE and Second time TRUE so it does not look practical.

```
Applicable = False
For Each chkRow As DataRow In chk.Rows
   For Each dtRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
      If chkRow("ProductCode") = dtRow("Code") Then
         Applicable = True
         Exit For
       Else
         Applicable = False
       End If
    Next
Next
```

Please suggest better solution.

Comment: Your question has been rolled back to the original version, which has an answer. Such a drastic edit changes the original question too much, and you should consider creating a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to use a LINQ query:

```vb
Dim codes = table1.AsEnumerable().
                   Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("Code"))
Dim productCodes = table2.AsEnumerable().
                          Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("ProductCode")).
                          ToArray()

If codes.All(Function(code) productCodes.Contains(code)) Then
    '...
End If
```

Note that there is a ToArray call for the *productCodes* but not *codes*. That's because *productCodes* needs to be enumerated multiple times and you don't want to do that on a deferred query.

Comment: @abdullah, Declare it.

Comment: @abdullah, it appears that I originally used the wrong name for Lambda parameters but @Jimi has kindly edited that for us. That's what I get for typing code directly into an answer instead of into the IDE and then copy/pasting. I've also added a missing closing parenthesis to the `If` statement.